# Is it possible to use a SQL date with a dynamic year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, variables, set

Is it possible to set a variable where the year is a variable?

For example,

Instead of

```
SET @Date1 = '2014-01-25 00:00:00.000';
```

I want

```
SET @Year = 2014 int;
SET @Date1 = '@Year-01-25 00:00:00.000';
```

Comment: `SET @Date1 = @Year + '-01-25 00:00:00.000'`  @Year will have to be a string however.

Comment: @paqogomez Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 16
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Comment: `SET @Date1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Year) + '-01-25 00:00:00.000'` Casting the `@Year` to a string, as @paqogomez stated in his comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

Many different ways including DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day )

```
@Date1 = DATEFROMPARTS (2014,01,25)
```

Comment: Also including cast(), depending on the db engine.

Comment: This is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** which is not available in earlier version

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SET @Date1 = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(4), @Year) + '-01-25', 102)
```

That number 102 as the 3rd parameter is the style used to convert. You can see a complete list of styles here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
scroll down to `Date and Time styles`